# How to make list item text hover color work correctly when it contains an anchor?

Tags: html, css

I have this html code and the nav has a red background with black text, and when you hover the text runs red and the background blue-ish. The thing is that the skins list item that has the anchor doesn't show the black text, and is always red, and only readable when you hover and the background turns darker. I tried moving the class to inside the anchor and that works but it only changes to red when you hover on the actual text, and not the list item.

If anyone can help me I would appreciate it!

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: hsl(358, 100%, 65%);
}

#skins {
  color: black;
}

#skins:hover {
  color: hsl(358, 100%, 65%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-primaria">
  <ul>
    <li id="skins"><a href="index.html">Skins</a></li>
    <li>Sobre Valorant</li>
    <li>Sobre Riot</li>
    <li>Ubicacion</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is your desired effect? What are you looking for your code to do?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the text is inside `<a>` not `<li>` so use :

```css
#skins a {
   /*your code*/
}
```

Comment: Nope, it makes it turn red when I hover on the text, and it has a weird behaviour where sometimes after the hover it stays red so it looks like it dissapeared, then if you hover again sometimes in turns back to black. idk

Comment: maybe because its a link so it does so

Comment: may i ask what exactly you are looking for as a result ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the red text on `:hover` then you can set `text-decoration: none;` with `color: initial` on your `a` element.

```css
a {
  color: initial;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: hsl(358, 100%, 65%);
}
```

```html
<nav class="nav-primaria">
  <ul>
    <li id="skins"><a href="index.html">Skins</a></li>
    <li>Sobre Valorant</li>
    <li>Sobre Riot</li>
    <li>Ubicacion</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Nope, it turns red only when you hover on the text and not on the whole <li>. Plus it makes all the other elements with <a> turn black, although i think you can change that with another attribute